# Maximize disc in polygon

Tags: geometry, optimization

The question is as follows:
Four coordinates $(0,0)$, $(1,4)$, $(4,2)$ and $(3,0)$ create a polygon. What is the largest disc that can fit within the polygon?

I have a formula for calculating the maximum distance ($d$) from the center point $(x_1,x_2)$, but I´m not sure if it is correct or how to get a reliable answer.

$d=\left|\frac{x_2-ax_1-b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right|$

Where $y=ax+b$ are the four sides of the polygon described as lines.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation

Comment: There are two more vital points, the line intersections {7, 0}, {-3, -12}.  With those, construct two triangles, then find the Incircle

Comment: I´m sorry, but I don´t follow. What two triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ denote the center and $r$ the radius.  The problem is to maximize
$$r=\min\left(
\frac{|-y_0|}{\sqrt{1}}, 
\frac{|-4x_0 + y_0|}{\sqrt{17}}, 
\frac{|2x_0 - y_0 - 6|}{\sqrt{5}}, 
\frac{|2x_0 + 3y_0 - 14|}{\sqrt{13}}
\right)$$
subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
- y_0 &\le 0 \\                                                              
- 4x_0 + y_0 &\le 0 \\                                                      
2x_0 - y_0 - 6 &\le 0 \\                                                    
2x_0 + 3y_0 - 14 &\le 0 
\end{align}

Here is SAS code for this nonlinear programming formulation:

```
proc optmodel;
   set LINES = {<0,-1,0>,<-4,1,0>,<2,-1,-6>,<2,3,-14>};

   var X0, Y0;

   max R = min {<a,b,c> in LINES} (abs(a * X0 + b * Y0 + c) / sqrt(a^2 + b^2));

   con CenterInside {<a,b,c> in LINES}:
      a * X0 + b * Y0 + c <= 0;
    
   solve with nlp / multistart;

   print X0 Y0 R;
quit;
```

This formulation can also be linearized: maximize $r$
subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\frac{-(-y_0)}{\sqrt{1}} &\ge r \\ 
\frac{-(-4x_0 + y_0)}{\sqrt{17}} &\ge r \\ 
\frac{-(2x_0 - y_0 - 6)}{\sqrt{5}} &\ge r \\ 
\frac{-(2x_0 + 3y_0 - 14)}{\sqrt{13}} &\ge r \\ 
- y_0 &\le 0 \\                                                              
- 4x_0 + y_0 &\le 0 \\                                                      
2x_0 - y_0 - 6 &\le 0 \\                                                    
2x_0 + 3y_0 - 14 &\le 0 
\end{align}

From either formulation, the resulting optimal solution turns out to be $(x_0,y_0,r)=(1.956, 1.5272, 1.5272)$:
[image]

As @EdPegg hinted, you can obtain this as the incenter of a triangle:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=incenter+%280%2C0%29+%281%2C4%29+%287%2C0%29

But not the incenter of this triangle:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=incenter+%281%2C4%29+%284%2C2%29+%28-3%2C-12%29

Comment: do you use the formula above to gain the r min, because I get some two of them as negative. Also, why are the constraints <= 0?

Comment: All four arguments in the $\min$ formula are nonnegative.  Did you forget the absolute value?  The constraints are $\le 0$ because the center $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the interior of the polygon.

Comment: Yes I forgot that there it is an absolute value. I´m looking to optimize it, how would I most easily proceed with that on my own?

Comment: Do you want to solve as NLP or LP?

Comment: NLP is what I am aiming for

Comment: Then you want to maximize the $\min$ function.

Comment: I can´t seem to figure out how to describe the function I am going to optimize. Is it x^2 + y^2 or is it r = ... ? And if it is r, do I need to program the four different functions separatelly? What does your programming solution look like? Thank you so much for keeping up with me!

Answer (score 0):

Extend all the sides infinitely. You get two triangles that contain the quadrilateral. For each of these triangles, use the [formula](https://mathinstructor.net/2012/10/how-to-find-area-of-inscribed-circle-in-a-triangle-with-three-given-sides-of-triangle/#:%7E:text=To%20find%20area%20of%20inscribed%20circle%20in%20a,be%20used%20to%20find%20area%20of%20inscribed%20circle.) for the area of the triangle's incircle. The smaller incircle is the largest circle that can be inscribed in the quadrilateral.

Using this method, the radius of the largest circle in the quadriateral is  $\frac{28}{\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{52}+7}\approx1.52719985$, which matches @RobPratt's answer.

(Optional short-cut: You can use the four side lengths of the quadrilateral and [Pitot's theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/pitots-theorem/) to determine which triangle will have the smaller incircle.)